# Website loading time over 20 seconds, only sometimes

Tags: loading, performance

I have a website that every 10-15 minutes it becomes very slow regarding loading times. This only started to happen today and before this the website loading time was under 2s, now it's over 20 seconds.

This is a pingdom report http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/WXaNJ/http://www.walkingoutlet.it/ which shows a `waiting time of 27s` The request are not much, 3 CSS's, 2/3 JS's at most and some images. I don't know if is some problem with the hosting company or with my website, I am not familiar with the technical part so just by the numbers of the report, could you tell me what the problem may be ?

I hope this question fits here because I don't know where to post it elsewhere.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The sources for all your content looks good and should normally be fast. I did see the largest
 image sfondo.jpg wasn't visible anywhere (is it that tiny band at the top) and if you could get rid of the gray crosshatch of the second largest outlet-online-scarpe.jpg it would probably be a lot smaller.

In general the small jpgs that are being delivered from your own web server are delivered kind-of slow in the pingdom report. That is probably because the pingdom servers are located distantly from your own server. You might want to try a website testing site that is located closer to your server or (even better) move your site to be located at a more central and faster host.

Comment: What do you mean by wasn't visible ? If I go to the image path I can see it, can't you ? Anyway, the pingdom servers being distant from my server should have a small impact, but 20s+ is something very strange. I would like to know if this could have something to do with the actual code ( php/mysql ) or is a hosting problem that I have no influence on. Thank you for your response.

Comment: "wasn't visible" - just meaning that if it isn't visually contributing to the page then it doesn't need to be loaded. But I believe I am seeing a little of it at the very top of your page but you could probably replace it with a much smaller image since you are just showing a sliver of it at the top.

It loads quick for me and for me using pingdom. My guess would be your site's host but don't have any evidence.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, now it loads fine for me too, but sometimes it takes 20s+ and my best guess is that the hosting is at fault.